# Curso de java pildoras informaticas

Tags: java

¿Alguien que ha llevado el curso  de java de pildoras informaticas por favor me podria decir que programas, herramientas,drivers ,etc usa el profe juan en este curso? 
Sucede que me ire de viaje a un lugar sin coneccion a internet, pero quiero aprender java, asi que decidi descargarme todo el curso de java de pildoras informaticas ,pero asumo que en el transcurso necesitare algunos programas ,herramientas o relacionados que nesecite descargar de internet ,pero como no tendre internet me perjudicaria totalmente ,por eso ya quiero descargar todo ahora para no tener problemas en el curso. 
gracias.

Comment: Voto por cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque  no versa sobre un problema de programación, por favor lee [ask]

Comment: Bienvenido por favor date una vuelta por el [tour] y de paso checa [ask], tu pregunta no posee dudas de programación y por tanto creo terminará cerrada

Comment: No tendriamos ni idea que es un curso de java de pildoras informaticas, y menos quien es el profe juan. Chequea los enlaces que te pasaron, pero este sitio es global a todo el mundo.

Comment: Disculparme , pense que  como esta comunidad es tan grande ,supuse que almenos 1 conoceria este curso de youtube  y me podria dar datos sobre su experiencia en el mismo

Comment: No hay problema @OsLan1999. Ten en cuenta los enlaces sobre que se puede preguntar aca. Tal vez te convenga preguntarle eso a quien imparte el curso...

Comment: @OsLan1999 utiliza solo el IDE eclipse, adicional a eso hace bastante referencia a la API de java, para explicar mejor los métodos y constantes, a veces los muestra en el vídeo y a veces no, es bastante detallado al explicar, así que además de el IDE y el jdk no debería faltar más :)

Comment: Es un excelente profesor Juan, Supongo que te bastara con instalar Java y el IDE, eso lo ves en sus primeros vídeos. Muy buenos tutoriales.

Comment: El profe juan es un gran programador!